# add Root tag in existing xml file using batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am trying to combine the a number xml files into single xml file using batch file. While combining I want to add root tag like >Master_File> for that combined xml.I wrote a Batch file to combine, but I can't able to add a Root Tag.

Batch File :

```
del combined.xml
REM set count to 1
set cnt=1
REM for each file that matches *.xml
for %%i in (*.xml) do (
REM if count is 1 it's the first time running
if !cnt!==1 (
REM push the entire file complete with header into combined.xml - this will also create combined.xml
for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.xml
REM otherwise, make sure we're not working with the combined file and
 ) else if %%i NEQ combined.xml (
REM push the file without the header into combined.xml
for /f " delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.xml
)
REM increment count by 1
set /a cnt+=1
)
```

Current resulted xml:

```
<xml1>
   <a>...</a>
</xml1>
<xml2>
   <b>...</b>
</xml2>
  <xml3>
   <c>...</c>
</xml3>
```

expected output xml after combine is

```
<Master_File>
<xml1>
   <a>...</a>
</xml1>
<xml2>
   <b>...</b>
</xml2>
  <xml3>
   <c>...</c>
</xml3>
</Master_File>
```

Can anyone help to achieve this please!

Comment: To combine multiple text files you could use `copy /A source1 + source2 + source3 + ... destination` (a tells the command to treat each source file as text file)...

Comment: What about [XML Declaration](https://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml) like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`?